# Python, kivy where to start?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

New to programing(learning python3) and I'm wanting to use kivy. Just wondering how people recommend learning it all and what exactly needs to be learnt in order to make small games and apps(I'm thinking for android but not sure yet) using kivy and python. Basically what do I need to learn first, how much do I need to know and what(if anything) else needs to be learnt?

Comment: Just to observe, kivy only supports python2 on android right now, though I'm working on fixing that. As a beginner, I wouldn't be too worried about that for now (they're very similar languages, despite what all the arguments might make you think), but just so you know.

Comment: Oh good to know, thanks. Well I've already started learning python 3 what would u recommend doing starting again but with python 2 or carry on with 3 and hope its not too long before it supports 3?

Comment: No, learning python3 is good, it's the future after all. But to be clear, even if at some point you need to do some python2, you wouldn't remotely have to start again - like I said, they're very similar languages, and it's often very easy to write code that works in both. For instance, all of kivy is compatible with both python2 and python3, and many libraries do the same thing.

Comment: Also, I don't think this is a very good question for stackoverflow, it's a better fit for specific technical questions. To answer loosely, you can start kivy by following its tutorials and others available on the internet (I have some [mostly-video tutorials](http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/)), and personally I recommend doing some basic python tutorials and small projects first, but some people do successfully use kivy while learning to make their first non-trivial programs.

Comment: Just to get this right then I should just stick to learning python for now then move on to learning kivy(don't want to confuse myself trying both at the same time lol). What roughly should i be able to do/right with python before I start getting involved with kivy? I'll check out your videos as well. Thanks for being a great help

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [url](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html)
Where it reads:

```
Note
Python 3 support on Android is now available experimentally.
```

You may better practice on Python2 where Kivy works. I gave some hard shots on make it work on Python3 but it failed in most cases.